# Correct way to use navbar and container in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement this layout:
[image]

Body's element has two children: `navbar` and `container-md`. The ideas is to have navbar without padding. Inside `container` there are three items and the middle one should fill all the space in height.

I use this html, but [it's not really working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lfnn6x?file=index.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Example 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <span class="navbar-brand h1 text-white">Navbar</span>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Container -->
    <div class="container-md">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)">Topbar</div>
        <div style="background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1)" class="flex-grow-1">
          Should fill all available space
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)">Bottombar</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also I tried to play with `min-vh-100` and `h-100` classes combination on some elements like `body` or `div.container` itself. The closest was adding `vh-100` to the `container`, but by doing this the body height would equal `100vh + navbar.height`, which is not what I want. I don't need any scrolls.

Of course I can try to use `calc(100% - navbar.height)`, but it's kinda strange.

So my question are how to implement this layout?

Should I actually include `navbar` inside `container` in best-practices approach?

Comment: How about if you add height: 100% (or h-100) to html, body and .container-md element?

Comment: @Shoejep, then the `container` is 100% height, and the body - 100% + navbar. Looks like I have to add `flex-shrink: 0` somewhere, but can't really get where exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so wrapping everything inside `d-flex flex-column` solves it:

```html
<html class="h-100"> <-- Add class here
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Example 1</title>
</head>
<body class="h-100">  <-- Add class here
    <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">  <-- Add this wrapper
      <!-- Navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <span class="navbar-brand h1 text-white">Navbar</span>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <!-- Container -->
      <div class="container-md d-flex flex-column h-100">
        <div style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)">Topbar</div>
        <div style="background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1)" class="flex-grow-1">
          Should fill all available space
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)">Bottombar</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also note, that you have to use `h-100` for `html` and `body` as well.

The only question is would it suite "best-practices"?